# Caching/Storing information for Android project

Tags: android, django, caching, persistence, storage

I am designing an Android application where I need to fetch some data from a third party project and display it for some users to see.

The thing is, I need to minimize the impact the accesses to the Android application will have in the third party system. As such, I was thinking of caching/storing the data in some way in my backend (thinking of going Python + Django since it is what I am most familiar with, but feel free to suggest others, always good to learn more!) so that the Android users don't access the third party project data directly (i.e. only one access to the third party project is made every X seconds to refresh the data and the users have access to whatever information is available when they use the application).

What is the best way of doing this? Should I store the data in a simple database? Or just dump the data in a file and work from there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that will depends on your requirement of storage and persistence level and type of data your storing. check the below links.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html

Comment: I believe the data will most likely be text and numbers (gps coordinates, equipment status, etc.).
From what I am reading in those links you posted, a simple SQLite database may solve my problems.. would be great to read more opinions on this though :)

Comment: As for the persistence level, the data needs to be refreshed every few seconds (since it's GPS data) and it must override the previously fetched data since it becomes obsolete.